# Remove part of url using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to remove part of url if it matches `//videoid?v=`

assuming my url can be

```
 - www.abc.com/video/
 - www.abc.com/video/videoid?v=1234567
 - www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567
```

in case url has `//` forward slash before `videoid?v=` then i need to remove single `/` from the url so that url will be correct such as `www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567`

`currentURL = document.URL;`

Comment: is that `www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567` would be correct url?

Comment: Except for the part following the protocol, is a double-slash ever correct in a URL? I'd suspect you don't need to first search for the `videoid` string (in most cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex and use it like this to remove double occurrences of "/":

```
"www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567".replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/os5yypqm/3/

**EDIT:**

I edited the JSFiddle to include "http://" in front of the url so that you can see that this does not affect it (and also read it here). Can't use it on SO though so you need to see the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

If your only concern is the double slash.

```
var currentUrl = 'www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567';
currentUrl.split('//').join('/');
```

Results in `www.abc.com/video/videoid?v=12345678`

Comment: @Learning the http:// wasn't in your provided string though. Next to that, this solution is probably slower than the regex replaces from the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace forward slash if followed by forward slash and `"v"`  with empty string

```
"www.abc.com/video//videoid?v=1234567".replace(/\/(?=\/v)/g, "")
```